Radius Bulk CoA message to BNG Juniper
I am working in BNG implementation with Juniper MX960 and I am interested in Bulk CoA feature to address accumulation of a series of CoA requests and commits all of them together. But I don't find any example of how send the bulk coa message from Radius.
According with the follow link:
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/subscriber-mgmt-services/topics/topic-map/dynamic-service-activation.html
"Bulk CoA requires each individual request to contain a single instance of the Juniper Networks Bulk-CoA-Transaction-Id VSA (26–194). This VSA identifies requests as belonging to the same bulk transaction; 26–194 must have the same value in all CoA requests in the bulk series. Each successive bulk transaction in the session must have a different identifier; for example, three successive bulk transactions can have IDs of 1, 2, and 1, but cannot have successive IDs of 1, 1, and 2. In practice, the Bulk-CoA-Transaction-Id value typically is incremented for multiple bulk transactions, but this is not required. An ID value used in a given subscriber session can also be used in different subscriber sessions."
Does anyone have an example of how to send this message from the Radius?
